# Laravel pass value from controller to route and then to controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Working my way through my first Laravel project. Thanks for all the help.

I have a SearchController that says if the count of the query is more then 1 to go to a view provided.

```
return view('pages/multi-providers')->with('data',$data)->with('city',$city)->with('state',$state)->with('provider',$provider)->with('zipcode',$zipcode);
```

I am able to pass the variables that were created in that simple way. But then the route is
    www.domain.com/search/?q=01035

So I tried to do a return redirect to a named route

```
return redirect()->route('multi-providers',[$zipcode])->with('data',$data)-  >with('city',$city)->with('state',$state)->with('provider',$provider)->with('zipcode',$zipcode);
```

Then my route in my routes.php is

```
Route::get('multi-providers/{zipcode}', ['uses' => 'PagesController@multiProviders','as' => 'multi-providers'])->with('data',$data)->with('city',$city)->with('state',$state)->with('provider',$provider)->with('zipcode',$zipcode);
```

And then in my PageController@multiProviders I have

```
public function multiProviders($zipcode)
    {
        $data['zipcode'] = $zipcode;
        return view('pages/multi-providers')->with('data',$data)->with('city',$city)->with('state',$state)->with('provider',$provider)->with('zipcode',$zipcode);

}
```

The route begins to work and it does show as

```
www.domain.com/multi-provider/{zipcode}(acutally shows zip like 92804)
```

But then I get an error that the $city and $state variables are not defined. So I tried passing them like the zipcode in the public function but then it says its missing an argument. Im guessing cause I dont have a extra parameter in the route like {city} or {state} in the url. Is there way to pass those variables without  them being in the URL? Or a different way to store them. I may be doing it a harder way then it should be. Thanks again for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this with a "compact"?

Like this in your public controller:

```
return view('pages.multi-providers', compact('zipcode', 'data', etc. etc.));
```

This makes it a little bit more readable and should pass those variables correctly.

Comment: I have not tried to use the "compact" code yet. Should I do that on all of them? I can pass the variables easy on the "return view" in the SearchController, But when I do "return redirect" to the named route. So I can get the correct URL "www.domain.com/multi-provider/{zipcode}.  I can not pass them to the PageController@multiProvider and then show them in the view there.

Comment: Did you tried to save those variables in session and then get them anywhere you need? In Laravel you can do it easily like that:

'session->put('nameOfVariable, 'value);
$someVariable = session()->get('someVariable');'

Comment: I have read a little about session but have not fully understood them yet. Do you have a link or article. I will read more on the Laravel Doc website. I dont understand how to take the values and store them from the query from the input. So if they search the zipcode, I need to store zipcode city state provider in the session. And then in the view or controller check for the session.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('multi-providers/{zipcode}/{city}/{state}/{provider}/{data}', ['uses' => 'PagesController@multiProviders','as' => 'multi-providers']);
```

and then you get in these variables from controller like this

```
public function multiProviders($zipcode, $city, $state, $provider, $data)
{

    return view('pages/multi-providers', compact('zipcode', 'city', 'state', 'provider', 'data'))}
```

And to go to this route with these parameters you should do this

```
return redirect()->route('multi-providers',compact('zipcode', 'city', 'state', 'provider', 'data'));
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make my url then www.domain.com/zipcode/city/state/provider/data? I would only want the zipcode in the URL and nothing else but still have those variables